# Set-Cookie header is not sent from azure web app

Tags: azure, express, cookies, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

I have a frontend that talks to a backend.
When logging in, the backend creates a cookie and returns it to the client.
When logging out, i want the backend to delete the cookie.

As you can see, i did not set any of the attributes below.

[image]

This is the request that is sent from the front.

```js
const response = await axios.get(
    `${backendAddress}/api/v1/auth/logout`,
    {
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: "include",
    }
);
```

This is what I do in the backend

```js
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `user-data=; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=${BACKEND_DOMAIN}`);
res.end();
```

and these are the cors configuration:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: CLIENT_URL, credentials: true }));
```

Locally, this works, I see the `Set-Cookie` header in the response and I can see that the browser deletes the cookie.

On azure, I run the backend as a web app in azure, and the frontend as a static web app, and connect both of them using the `api` feature of the static web app.

When i check what headers i receive on the same request that work locally, I can see that the `Set-Cookie` header is missing.

When looking at the request that is sent to the webapp (the backend), I do see that the cookies are sent with it. And that the cors headers in the response include the right origin and credential headers. I also made sure that the versions of both front and backend are up to date.

Any idea what might cause the `Set-Cookie` to "disappear" on its way to the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @ToreNestenius HTTPS

Answer (score -1):

It is because the origins of the cookie is from a different url and the browsers do not allow that.

I have been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).